# react native foreach Loop is not working perfectly

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, es6-promise, parallel.foreach

I am working on a react native application. on a screen, I am getting some images from the memory then read their stats(size, name, type). I have an array to store image objects. But I am getting strange behaviour. Here is my sample code.

```
const getPhotos =    () =>{
    RNFetchBlob.fs.ls(dirs_read)
    .then((data) =>{
      let i = 0 
      let items = []
      let arrOfImages =  data.filter((elem) => elem.endsWith('jpeg'))
      arrOfImages.forEach((child) =>{
        
        console.log('iteration', ++i)
        RNFetchBlob.fs.stat(`file://${dirs_read}${child}`).then((stats) =>{
        var dateTime = new Date(stats.lastModified);
        var path =stats.path;
          items.push({
            name: child,
            date: ('0' + dateTime.getUTCDate()).slice(-2) + '-' + ('0' + dateTime.getUTCMonth()).slice(-2) + '-' + dateTime.getUTCFullYear(),
            size: formatBytes(stats.size),
            type:'jpeg',
            path: path
          })
          console.log(items,'Items in Loop')
       }).catch((err) => {
         console.log('Some Eror in stats read')
       }) 
      console.log(items,' Items out of Loop')
      })      
    }).catch((error) =>{
     
    })
}
```

Here I am explaining what I am getting. in the `arrofImages` i am getting images from memory. I am iterating in this array and for each child, I read their status. to this point everything is fine. I have created and temporary array with name items. in that array in-store image with relevant data with the push method. Here **Problem is that the** `arrOfImages` **is executing first** and after that the `items.push` is executing. when I console the `items` array out of the `arrOfImages` then this is empty. Here I have an out on the console.
[image]

I want that when all I get all data then after that I want to show that.
if I call the `setState` function immediately after the `item.push` then I am getting the data but it is loading slowly. means one by one. I want it smoothly.

Comment: This is just ordinary asynchronous behavior.  Correct, `console.log(items,' Items out of Loop')` will run prior to `RNFetchBlob.fs.stat` completing fully.

Comment: how can i do this. means after completing RNFetchBlob.fs.stat then I want to set my state.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your function into an async function. With that keyword await you are telling the async function to wait on that line until RNFetchBlob is ready. When it's ready you can work with that result.

```
const getPhotos = async () => {
    const data = await RNFetchBlob.fs.ls(dirs_read);
    // The following code will now be executed when RNFetchBlob is ready and data is accessible.
    let i = 0;
    let items = [];
    let arrOfImages = data.filter((elem) => elem.endsWith("jpeg"));
    // and so on ...
  };
```

Comment: I have already applied the above solution. problem is with `RNFetchBlob.fs.stat` function.

Comment: You can try to work with await for the lower function fs.stat as well.

Comment: i have already tried this like. `let stats = await RNFetchBlob.fs.stat(`file://${dirs_read}${child}`)`. but have the same result.

Answer (score 1):

We need to change two things.

1. Use async-await instead of Promises;
2. Use For of loop instead of forEach loop

Please check with below code. i think this will resolve your issue.

```
    const getPhotos = async () => {
    try {

      let data = await RNFetchBlob.fs.ls(dirs_read);

      let i = 0
      let items = []
      let arrOfImages = data.filter((elem) => elem.endsWith('jpeg'))
      for (const child of arrOfImages) {
        console.log('iteration', ++i)
        try {

          let stats = await RNFetchBlob.fs.stat(`file://${dirs_read}${child}`);
          var dateTime = new Date(stats.lastModified);
          var path = stats.path;
          items.push({
            name: child,
            date: ('0' + dateTime.getUTCDate()).slice(-2) + '-' + ('0' + dateTime.getUTCMonth()).slice(-2) + '-' + dateTime.getUTCFullYear(),
            size: formatBytes(stats.size),
            type: 'jpeg',
            path: path
          })
          console.log(items, 'Items in Loop')
        } catch ((err) => {
          console.log('Some Eror in stats read')
        })
      }
      console.log(items, ' Items out of Loop')

    } catch ((error) => {

    });
  }
```